# css3 vertical division of 3/3 in 1/3 and 2/3 blocks

Tags: css, flexbox

I thought i was was able to use flexbox this but i don't find any information on this. I tried searching for vertical layouts using flexbox but i wasn't able to succeed.

Basically what i want is the following scenario:

I have 3/3 of height and i want to divide it using css (if this is possible offcourse)
in 2 parts, one part takes 1/3 and another 2/3

```
_______
| 1/3 |
-------
| 2/3 |
|     |
-------
```

I know i can do this with javascript, and that is what i'm currently doing, but i thought css3 brought this possibility or am i wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the height of the `body` and `html` to 100%, then set each element to the height you want. Add in `overflow: hidden` to prevent growing of the divs. Vertical margins will ruin this layout, so use padding.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pux7q/4/)**

CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.top {
    height: 33.3333%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: blue;
}

.bottom {
    height: 66.6666%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to accomplish this is using `position:absolute;` which allows you to use this 1-2/3 div somewhere other than as a direct child of body. See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A7N4y/):

```
body{margin:0;padding:0;}
.container{position:absolute;height: 100%;background-color:green;}
.ot{height: 33%;background-color:red;}
.tt{height:67%;background-color:yellow;}
```

For example, set the `height` of .container to `300px` to see the effect.

Comment: And if you are using set heights (in px or ems), you can use `position: relative` so any content underneath will still flow. http://jsfiddle.net/A7N4y/1/